# Magento to find shopping cart rule match by product programmatically?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, module, mysql

**Question Updated**

I am being try to find the discount amount which match the shopping cart rule based on product. I replicate the module 'Shopping Cart Price Rule' to another module which i want to create my discount rule under condition tab.My new module does not have coupon code.It has rule information and  condition only.

So Here i want to get discount amount that matches my new module rule based on product details(product id, sku) with out coupon code.

```
/**
 * Get rules collection for current object state
 *
 * @return Mage_SalesRule_Model_Mysql4_Rule_Collection
 */
protected function _getRules()
{
    $key = $this->getWebsiteId() . '_' . $this->getCustomerGroupId() . '_' . $this->getCouponCode();
    return $this->_rules[$key];
}
```

Here we dont use $this->getCouponCode() to find the rule match.

Before going to replicated module, i just want to know is it possible in shopping cart price rule module.

My question is , How do i find the discount amount based on product that matches shopping cart price rule with out giving coupon code ?

Comment: sorry this is not an answer but have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595296/magento-get-salesrule-id-from-product-id-or-entity-id

Comment: @DavidManners Is it possible to get shopping cart price rule from order ?

Comment: maybe if you add your cart rule it would be easier to understand and help

Comment: @DavidManners i need some thing like Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Resource_Rule::getRulesForProduct(). I just want to know the product matches shopping(or my new module) rule once it is added and return its discount amount

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried with external file,Given product id to find the matched sales rule conditions.

```
require_once("app/Mage.php");

Mage::app('default'); 

$pid = 53;
$_product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pid);

$coll = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/rule_collection')->load();
foreach($coll as $rule){
  $rule->afterLoad(); 
}  

 $quoteId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId(); 
 $real_quote = Mage::getSingleton('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);                
 $product = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->setQuote($real_quote)->setProduct($_product);  
 $product->setAllItems(array($_product));                 
 $product->getProduct()->setProductId($_product->getEntityId());    
foreach($coll as $rule) 
{  
    if ($rule->getConditions()->validate($product))  
    {            
       echo ':)';
       echo $rule->getData('discount_amount');
  }        
}   
exit;
```

Comment: @DavidManners I almost came with one solution.Now i need to do the same with my replicated module.

Comment: @DavidManners Actually, I use flag to filter salerule grid and my module rule grid.I have changed my new module based on salerule table now.To avoid more complexity i use magento salerule module to validate :)

Comment: Great solution, Very helpful (y)